# Two commutative diagram connected by arrow

Tags: tikz-cd

I want the draw the following diagram[image]

Comment: Hello @Manish Kumar Singh! Welcome to TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange! You should write a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe). Than is it much easier to help you.

For your [question](http://www.jmilne.org/not/CDGuide.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry, some parts of your screenshot I can't read.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=1.4cm,column sep=1.4cm]
A\arrow[d]\arrow[rr]& & A_1\arrow[d]\\
A_2\arrow[rr]& & A'
\end{tikzcd}
~\xRightarrow{~~~~~~}~
\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture]
& m & & & m\\[-0.5cm]
&\mathfrak{p}(A)\arrow[d]\arrow[rr]& &\mathfrak{p}(A_1)\arrow[d]&\\
&\mathfrak{p}(A_2)\arrow[rr]& & \mathfrak{p}(A') & \\[-0.2cm]
&m_2& & ~ &
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\typeout{\tikzcdmatrixname}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[anchor=west,xshift=-6pt] at (\tikzcdmatrixname-4-4) (extra) {$m_2\otimes A'=m_1\otimes A_1$};
\draw[dashed,-latex] (\tikzcdmatrixname-3-2.north west) to[out=135,in=-135]
(\tikzcdmatrixname-1-2);
\draw[dashed,-latex] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-5.north west) to[out=135,in=45]
(\tikzcdmatrixname-2-2.north east);
\draw[-latex] (\tikzcdmatrixname-4-2.south east) to[out=-45,in=-135]
(\tikzcdmatrixname-4-4);
\draw[-latex] (\tikzcdmatrixname-1-5.south east) to[out=-45,in=90]
(extra.46);
}
\end{document}
```